# In FluentAssertions, why is Should a method instead of a property?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

In FluentAssertions, you can make various claims in various formats.

```
x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(y);
x.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(y);
```

are both valid assertions.

Why is `Should` a method and not a property? I haven't seen any examples in which `Should` takes a parameter, so it seems to me like it could have easily been a property.

You can also assert that

```
x.Should().NotBeNull().And.BeEquivalentTo(y);
```

Here, `And` is a property instead of a method. Shouldn't `And` and `Should` each be the same type of element (methods/properties)?

**TL;DR**
Was there a valid reason behind the design choice to make `Should` a method in FluentAssertions instead of a property?

Comment: I don't think the chaining works if you try to use a property.  IOW the method-chaining technique requires methods.

Comment: @DavidTansey But they are performing chaining with the `And` property.

Comment: Chaining merely requires that an object is returned.  You can chain using methods or properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Should()` is an extension method being added onto the class of `x`.  You can only add extension methods -- C# doesn't have *extension properties*.

`And` is a property on whatever class `NotBeNull()` returns.  There we have control over the class, and can add real properties to it.

Answer (score 3):

`Should()` is a method because of the limitations of the C# language. It's an extension method; a method that is defined in the `FluentAssertions` library to be available to call on any type (hence `x.Should()`) - even though the original code for the class doesn't implement the method.

You can't implement extension *properties*, so `Should` has to be a method.

That method returns an object defined within `FluentAssertions`, as does `NotBeNull()`, and so these objects can include properties where it's relevant/useful/meaningful to do so.

In short: the valid reason is that it's the only choice available.